# KendoUI Grid custom sortable object alert or breakpoint not hit

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to enforce a custom sortable compare function for some columns in a Kendo Grid, specifically some currency values that can be negative, null, 0, or positive. I am seeing inconsistent sorting across browsers and so tried to put a break point or an alert into the custom sortable object's function, but neither is being hit.

Here is an example of the setup for the Salary column. The Salary field is setup as type number.

```
{
    field: "Salary",
    format: "{0:c2}",
    sortable: {
        compare: function (a, b) {
            x = kendo.parseFloat(a);
            y = kendo.parseFloat(b);
            if (isNaN(x) || x === null) {
                x = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(y) || y === null) {
                y = 0;
            }
            alert('x = ' + x + '; ' + 'y = ' + y);
            return (x === y ? 0 : ((x > y) ? 1 : -1));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a JSFiddle all set up to demonstrate this behavior located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krq6G/10/).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571402/custom-sorting-in-kendoui-grid-datasource) does not provide an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the field that you want to sort by.  For example, FirstName.

```
sortable: {
    compare: function (a, b) {
        return (a.FirstName === b.FirstName ? 0 : ((a.FirstName > b.FirstName) ? 1 : -1));
    }
}
```

I also think you didn't have your references to kendo and jQuery correct in your fiddle.  Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Yb3G2/

Comment: It would appear that perhaps our version (2013.1.319) is to blame. As soon as I change your fiddle to that version, the alert is no longer hit. I had already experimented with the fieldnames in the sortable custom object as well. Thanks.